# Как работает программа показа живых обоев на рабочем столе (winVista/7/8/8.1)?

Tags: directx, c++

Существует программа **DreamScenes**, которая позволяет устанавливать видео обои на рабочий стол (обычное видео в формате dream/wmv/mpg). Также в **VLC media player** есть функция показа видео в режиме обоев (исходники данной программы доступны, но разобраться в них не получилось: [Исходники](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html)). Как выглядит код, реализующий такую фичу?
Пока я смогла реализовать такое "чудо" таким образом (примерный код, рабочий):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA File;
    HANDLE F;
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)  {
    F=FindFirstFile("C:\\leto\\*.jpg", &File);
    if (F!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {        do
                {
                ofstream bat("C:\\logo.bat", ios_base::out);
                bat << "REG ADD \"HKCU\\Control Panel\\Desktop\" /v Wallpaper /d \"C:\\leto\\" << File.cFileName <<"\" /f" << endl <<
                "rundll32.exe user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters" << endl;
                bat.close();
                system("C:\\logo.vbs");
                Sleep(200);
                }
             while (FindNextFile(F,&File)!=0);
                FindClose(F);
    }
}
    system("pause");
}
```

**Описание:** В папке находятся картинки (кадры анимации). Находим первую картинку, в батнике прописываем код, который меняет обои рабочего стола на мою картинку, запускаем vbs-скрипт, который позволяет выполнять батник в фоновом режиме, затем делаем паузу между выполнением следующей команды в программе С++ (0.2 сек). Таким образом наблюдается анимация на рабочем столе (но на первом проходе она виснет, почти не выполняется, потом работает, в этом и проблема). Как реализовать нормально, без зависа и кучи картинок, как в упомянутых в начале темы программах?

Comment: Нашла в исходниках VLC media player файлы directx.c и vlc_playlist.h, которые отвечают за видео-обои. Используется DirectShow. Не думаю, что сама разберусь, эта тема для меня - темный лес. Т.е. нужно писать видео-плеер, в который затем запилить фичу из тех файлов?

Comment: разбираться с DirectX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отрисовку можно сделать посредством DirectDraw, вот [тут](http://www.angelcode.com/dev/overlay/) есть пример.

**Но**, решение несовместимо с Aero, придется выключать.